# How to fit an image feature to a curve

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I process a bunch 2D each having a sinusoidal feature randomly located in it:

[image]

Whereas the amplitude and the period of the sine are known in advance, the exact position is not.

I want to find an exact position of the sine in each image using MATLAB. Standard fitting techniques like [Surface Fit](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/evaluate-a-surface-fit.html) won't work here because I only need to fit one feature, not the whole image.

The best idea that comes to my mind is to generate a reference image with a sine with a known location, and then use cross-corrrelation ([xcorr2](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html)) to find the offset between the two. Maybe you could suggest any faster and simpler solution?

Comment: This question would probably fit better on [stats.SE] or [dsp.SE]

Comment: hmmm i would totally operate over the image to get a more clear signal (binarized if it's possible) then use the points as an xy  coordinates and fit f = a*sin(w*x-t) +b or something like that

Comment: Yeah that's the standard solution: Convolution/cross-correlation with a filter that contains the desired feature. You can improve performance/accuracy by filtering the image and converting to black-and-white, but no need to make a simple task more complicated unless you need to.

Comment: To gain speed, perform the correlation in the Fourrier space with fft2.